# A Plücker coordinate matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics, grassmannians, matroid-theory

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let
$\mathrm{Gr}(V,d)$ be the set (Grassmann variety) of all
$d$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. We can regard
$\mathrm{Gr}(V,d)$ as a subset of the vector space
$\Lambda^d(V)$ (of dimension ${n\choose d}$) via the Plücker
embedding. Thus $\mathrm{Gr}(V,d)$ defines a matroid
$\mathrm{Pl}(V,d)$ (where independence corresponds to linear
independence in $\Lambda^d(V)$). Can anything interesting be
said about this matroid?

In particular, there is a "natural" matroid structure on
$\mathrm{Gr}(V,d)$, namely, the matroid corresponding to the $d$th
[Dilworth
truncation](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-3558-8_29) $D_d \mathbb{B}(V)$ of the lattice $\mathbb{B}(V)$ of
all subspaces of $V$. Is $D_d \mathbb{B}(V)$ isomorphic to
$\mathrm{Pl}(V,d)$?

Comment: Can you give a quick self-contained definition of a Dilworth truncation? I must have forgotten it, and the reference isn't all that useful.

Comment: Is the Dilworth truncation of a matroid the same as defined in Definition 12.2.1 of [H. Narayanan, *Submodular functions and electrical networks*, 2nd edition 2019](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~hn/book/SubmodularFunction_2ed.pdf), applied to the rank function of the matroid?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: a quick (but not so easy to work with) definition is the following. Let $L$ be a geometric lattice of rank $n$. Let $1\leq d\leq n-1$. Then the matroid $M$ corresponding to $D_dL$ has as points the elements of $L$ of rank $d$. A subset $S$ of points of $M$ is independent if the join of any $k$ elements of $S$ has rank at least $d+k-1$ in $L$.

Comment: is the following correct reformulation? "if $A$ is a collection of $d$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, then the corresponding Plücker elements of $\Lambda^d(V)$ are linearly independent if and only if the span of any $k$ subspaces from $A$ have dimension at least $d+k-1$"?

Comment: (if so, then this seems to be not true for three 2-dimensional coordinate subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: Just thinking that if the rank of a d-dimensional subspace was actually the minimum of $d$ and $n-d$ and if we use the orthogonal complement if $d$ is larger than $n/2$, then there may be still hope that the 2 matroids are the same. We then avoid @FedorPetrov's counterexample. Just a thought.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: yes, in fact in general $\mathrm{Pl}(V,d)$ has full rank, i.e., ${n\choose d}$, while $D_d\mathbb{B}(V)$ has rank $n-d$. Perhaps $\mathrm{Pl}(V,d)$  has some nice properties, such as its number of flats of rank $k$ or characteristic polynomial. The simplest nontrivial case is $F=\mathbb{F}_2$, $n=4$, $d=2$. We are looking at a 35-point matroid in $\mathbb{F_2}^6$. Can someone do the computation?